# Calculate minimum number of students to go to series of lectures

Tags: algorithm, graph

Some students wants to minimize their lecture attendance by sending minimum number of students to each of `n` lectures.

- Lecture `i` begins at time `a[i]` and ends at time `b[i]`
- It requires `r[i][j]` time to commute from lecture `i` to lecture `j`

Is there any algorithm to calculate the minimum number of students needed to attend all lectures?

Comment: what does `minimum flow with lower bounds` mean??

Comment: Got confused?  What's confusing about it?  Tell us how far you understand it, eh?  Something like "At first I thought this was just the maximum overlap problem, but then I realized that since students take nonzero time to move between lectures, so I think that idea broke.  Any way to salvage it?"  ... if you can't even start thinking about it, what chance do you have at understanding the solution?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network

Comment: What are we trying to minimize here? Number of students subject to total cost <= C ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the classes as nodes in a graph. Construct edges between pairs of nodes `(i,j)` in the graph if it is possible to commute from lecture `i` to lecture `j` in time. The "root" nodes of your graph are the first classes of the day (classes that start before any other classes end in time to get to that class).

The first key observation is that the graph is directed and acyclic (you can't go back in time).

Your goal is to find the minimum number of paths through the graph such that every node is visited at least once. This immediately leads to the second key observation, which is that this can be accomplished greedily.

So the algorithm goes as follows:

1. Find the longest path in the directed acyclic graph (DAG)
2. Remove the nodes found in that path from the graph
3. Increment `minNumStudents`
4. Repeat until graph has no more nodes

Finding the longest path in a DAG is simple using dynamic programming:

1. Compute a [topological order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort) `ordering` of the graph
2. Keep an array `dist` with `V` elements (the number of nodes in the graph), initialized to `0`
3. Keep an array `prev` with `V` elements, storing the previous node in the path

Then

```
for each vertex `V` in `ordering`
    for each edge (V,W)
        dist[W] = min(dist[W],dist[V]+1)
        prev[W] = V;
```

Your longest path ends at the `W` such that `dist[W]` is maximum. And the longest path can be computed by backtracking from `W` using the `prev` array.